# Ecto changesets and GenServers using TDD

Tags: tdd, elixir, ecto, changeset, gen-server

I'm testing a `GenServer` by [unit testing the `handle_{call,cast,info}` callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028216/1693831). One of my **doctest**s is as follows:

```
@doc """                                                                                             
  Call the GenServer to retrieve the initial workout                                                   

  ## Examples                                                                                          
  iex> :rand.seed(:exsplus, {101, 102, 103})                                                           
  iex> Pullapi.GenServerWorker.handle_call({:initial_workout, 5}, nil, %{})                         
  {:reply,                                                                                             
  {:ok,                                                                                                
  [%{"Action" => "Pullups", "SequenceNo" => 0, "Units" => "1"},                                        
  %{"Action" => "Rest", "SequenceNo" => 1, "Units" => "60"},                                           
  %{"Action" => "Pullups", "SequenceNo" => 2, "Units" => "3"},                                         
  %{"Action" => "Rest", "SequenceNo" => 3, "Units" => "60"},                                           
  %{"Action" => "Pullups", "SequenceNo" => 4, "Units" => "3"},                                         
  %{"Action" => "Rest", "SequenceNo" => 5, "Units" => "70"}]}, %{}}                                    
  """
```

I want to insert the reply to the DB under a specified schema which has been realised in a migration. However I have no solid idea as to how I would write a unit test for this - since the DB write is essentially a side effect, the above **doctest** would stay the same.

Is it enough to somehow **doctest** the `changeset` independently, then place the `Repo.insert` into the `GenServer` given a test pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the piece of functionality you're trying to cover in DocTests has side effects, and this, as due to documentation is discouraged.

You can find more in the [*"When not to use doctest"* section](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.DocTest.html#module-when-not-to-use-doctest):

> In general, doctests are not recommended when your code examples contain side effects...

Comment: Can this be resolved by including the capturing some result of the insert  in the `handle_call` output - i.e the insert no longer becomes a side effect?

Comment: I think this could be interesting exercise for you if you would like to try couple of approaches, but in general, I wouldn't consider this the best way forward in your case. The main purpose of Docs is actually documenting the behaviour and if you're starting to affect you code the way to make it _testable in DocTests_, you might exposing to much of internals and how things are implemented. This feels like obscuring documentation making it less accessible. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for that. How does this compare to the TDD approach of writing a test first, then writing code to specifically pass the test? Wouldn't TDD lead to code that is designed to be testable?

Comment: @category sorry for not being specific, let me fix that! TDD is great technique, and you should follow it, the point I was trying to make is that - the kind of testing you're trying to do is valid and you have to test you functions more granularly, but DocTests is not the best place for doing that. This kind of testing should be handled in your `_test.exs` files. With this approach, you should end up with tested code (in test files) and clean, easy to understand documentation. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks, yes - if an `ExUnit` test is best in this case, should I also replace my previous `doctests` with `ExUnit` tests for consistency?

Comment: It's bit difficult to judge based on the example of one function you have shared here, but and yes and no: *yes* move testing code to test files (you want to keep testing your code), and *no*, leave "Examples" section in doc tests (in the end, this is documentation, so showing the way of using function is a good idea), but just don't run examples from them in your testing suite (which effectively boils down to amending, or removing completely `doctest MyModule` from your test files)

Comment: Excellent, thanks - that's exactly what I needed to know.